# Creating new Microsoft Application password throws error

Tags: azure, botframework

I created a new Bot Channel Registration in Azure.  From what I understand in order to [authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-core-authentication), I need an application Id and password from the Microsoft Application Registration portal.  When I make any changes and click "Save", I receive the error pictured below.  This doesn't happen if I create a Web App Service bot.  Any input on this error would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you check https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and see if you can create a new app with the same identity you used to log into azure?

Comment: @EricDahlvang I can.  And from Azure, I can create a WebApp Bot, and its corresponding app Id and password without issue.  Its specifically when the "Bot Channels Registration" is used in Azure.

Comment: The team is looking into this.

Comment: @EricDahlvang Whats the outlook on this?  days?  weeks?

Comment: A matter of days or hours.

Comment: The fix for this should be rolled out today.  In the mean time, I just learned about this: MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword can be found by navigating to the ResourceGroup for the Bot Registration, choosing “Deployments”, then the specific deployment for the bot.

Comment: @EricDahlvang yeah I saw that fix at the bottom of the article.  Thanks for the update.  Ill be on a lookout for the update.